# How to add a local filter to calendar using kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, filter

```
    private var modelList: ArrayList<PMDetailResponse.ResultBean>? = null
    private var modelListUnchecked: ArrayList<PMDetailResponse.ResultBean>? = null
    private lateinit var headerFilter: PMDetailResponse.ResultBean
    private var mDetailAdapter: PMDetailAdapter? = null
    lateinit var mPreventiveMaintenanceViewModel: PreventiveMaintenanceViewModel
    //var mDetailAdapter!!.mAnythingChecked = false
    var openedBy: String = ""
    var runQuery:String = ""
    var noDataReceived = false

    companion object {
        fun getInstance(): PMWorkOrderDueSoonFragment {
            return PMWorkOrderDueSoonFragment()
        }
    }

    private fun handleIncidentListApiResponse(
        pmResponses: PMDetailResponse,
        isHeaderNeedToAdd: Boolean
    ) {
        mPMResponse = pmResponses
        if (pmResponses.result != null) {
            var lstResult =
                pmResponses.result as ArrayList<PMDetailResponse.ResultBean>
            modelList = lstResult
            if (lstResult.size > 0) {
                setAdapter(
                    lstResult as ArrayList<PMDetailResponse.ResultBean>,
                    isHeaderNeedToAdd
                )
            } else
                showNoData(true)
        } else
            showNoData(true)
    }

    private fun showNoData(showNoData: Boolean) {
        mBindingFragmentGroupBinding.pmAssignedToDeviceRecycerparent.listIncidentNoRecordTv.visibility =
            if (showNoData) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
        mBindingFragmentGroupBinding.pmAssignedToDeviceRecycerparent.fragmentIncidentAssigntoHs.visibility =
            if (showNoData) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
    }

    private fun setAdapter(
        lstResult: ArrayList<PMDetailResponse.ResultBean>,
        isHeaderNeedToAdd: Boolean
    ) {

        mDetailAdapter = PMDetailAdapter(
            lstResult,
            this,
            true, false, mPreventiveMaintenanceViewModel
        )
        if (isHeaderNeedToAdd) {
            mDetailAdapter!!.addHeader()
        }
        mBindingFragmentGroupBinding.pmAssignedToDeviceRecycerparent.fragmentIncidentAssigntoDashboardRv.adapter =
            mDetailAdapter
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        mBindingFragmentGroupBinding =
            DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                inflater,
                R.layout.fragment_pm_assigned_to_device,
                container,
                false
            )
        return mBindingFragmentGroupBinding.root
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        mPMApiViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(PMApiViewModel::class.java)
        mPreventiveMaintenanceViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(PreventiveMaintenanceViewModel::class.java)
        setUIBackground()
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        mPMApiViewModel.callDuePMApi(PMAssignedStatus.DUE)
        callPmDueWOObserver()
        openedBy = SharedPreferenceManager.getString(
            WeakReference<Context>(activity?.baseContext),
            SharedPreferenceConstant.shared_pref_login_user_email
        ).toString()
    }

    private fun setUIBackground() {
        if (AppConstants.themeColor == Color.WHITE) {
            assign_layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
            fragment_incident_assignto_dashboard_rv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
            //linear_layout_assigned_to_hs.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
            //list_incident_no_record_tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)


        } else {
            assign_layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)
            fragment_incident_assignto_dashboard_rv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)
            //linear_layout_assigned_to_hs.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)
            //list_incident_no_record_tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
        }
    }

    override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)
        mMenu = menu
        clearMenu()

    }
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {

        val exportMenuItem: MenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.export_filter)
        var feedBackSubmitTextView =
            exportMenuItem.actionView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_export_bt)
        feedBackSubmitTextView.setText(getString(R.string.dispatch_pm_to_me))
        val exportActionView: View = exportMenuItem.getActionView()
        exportActionView.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
                onOptionsItemSelected(exportMenuItem)
            }
        })

      /*  val awesomeMenuItem: MenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.run_filter)
        val awesomeActionView: View = awesomeMenuItem.getActionView()
        awesomeActionView.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
                onOptionsItemSelected(awesomeMenuItem)
            }
        })*/
        menu.findItem(R.id.run_filter).isVisible = true
        menu.findItem(R.id.save_filter).isVisible = true
        menu.findItem(R.id.save_filter).setIcon(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.calendar));
        menu.findItem(R.id.icons_menu).isVisible = true
        menu.findItem(R.id.icons_menu).subMenu.findItem(R.id.action_barcode_scanner).isVisible =
            false
        menu.findItem(R.id.icons_menu).subMenu.findItem(R.id.attach).isVisible = false
        menu.findItem(R.id.icons_menu).subMenu.findItem(R.id.action_soti_device_details).isVisible =
            false
        menu.findItem(R.id.icons_menu).subMenu.findItem(R.id.run_pm_filter).isVisible = false
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {

            R.id.export_filter -> {
                Log.e("HistoricalFrag", "Export Button Selected")
                if(!noDataReceived) {
                    if (mDetailAdapter!!.mAnythingChecked) {
                        val jsonArray = updateList()
                        val pmDispatchRequest: PMDispatchRequestArray = PMDispatchRequestArray(jsonArray)
                        Log.i("jsonArray", "jsonArray::$jsonArray")
                        //val workOrderObj = JSONObject()
                        // workOrderObj.put("DispatchInfoList", jsonArray)
                        //val jsonStr = jsonArray.toString()
                        //Log.i("TAG", "jsonStr::$jsonStr")
                        mDetailAdapter!!.mAnythingChecked = false
                        if (!jsonArray.isEmpty()) {
                            mPMApiViewModel.callPMDispatchToMe(pmDispatchRequest)
                            setObserverForDispatchToMeAPI()
                        } else {
                            showToast("Please Select The CheckBox")
                        }

                    } else {
                        showToast("Please Select The CheckBox")
                    }
                }else{
                    showToast("Not allowed")
                }
                return true
            }
            R.id.run_filter -> {
                if(!noDataReceived) {
                    runQuery = ""
                    mDetailAdapter!!.mAnythingChecked = false
                    var runQuery = runPMFilter()
                    if (runQuery.isNotEmpty()) {
                        mDetailAdapter!!.removeHeader()
                        mDetailAdapter!!.clear()
                        callPmDueFilterObserver()
                        mPMApiViewModel.callFilterDuePMApi(runQuery, PMAssignedStatus.FILTER)
                    } else {
                        showToast("No Filter Provided")
                    }
                }else{
                    showToast("Not allowed")
                }
                return true
            }
            R.id.save_filter->{
                pickFromDateTime()
                return true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }

    private fun clearMenu() {
        mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(false)
        mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(false)
        mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_incident).setVisible(false)
        mMenu.findItem(R.id.export_filter).setVisible(true)
        mMenu.findItem(R.id.run_filter).setVisible(true)
        mMenu.findItem(R.id.icons_menu).setVisible(false)
    }

    private fun callPmDueWOObserver() {
        if (mPMApiViewModel.callDuePMWorkOrderResponseObserver()
                ?.hasActiveObservers()!!
        )
            mPMApiViewModel.callDuePMWorkOrderResponseObserver()?.removeObserver(
                pmResponseObserver
            )!!

        pmResponseObserver = Observer { value ->
            if (mPMApiViewModel.mIsResponseforDuePmWorkOrder) {
                if (value.apiStatus) {
                    showProgressDialog()
                } else {
                    mPMApiViewModel.mIsResponseforDuePmWorkOrder = false
                    hideProgressDialog()
                    try {
                        if (value.response != null && !value.response.equals(getString(R.string.server_error))) {
                            if (value.response is PMDetailResponse) {
                                val mPmList =
                                    value.response as PMDetailResponse
                                if (mPmList.result?.size!! > 0) {
                                    handleIncidentListApiResponse(mPmList, true)
                                } else
                                    showDialog(
                                        getString(R.string.error_msg),
                                        getString(R.string.no_response_server),
                                        true
                                    )
                            }
                        } else {
                            showToast(getString(R.string.server_error))
                            noDataReceived = true
                            showNoData(true)
                        }

                    } catch (ex: SocketTimeoutException) {
                        ex.printStackTrace()
                        LogOperation.getLogger().logInfo(
                            LogLevel.INFO_LOG,
                            "callPmDueWOObserver - Socket Time Out Exception : $ex"
                        )
                        showToast(getString(R.string.socket_timeout_error))
                    } catch (ex: Exception) {
                        ex.printStackTrace()
                        LogOperation.getLogger().logInfo(
                            LogLevel.INFO_LOG,
                            "callPmDueWOObserver - Exception : $ex"
                        )
                        showToast(getString(R.string.exception_error))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        mPMApiViewModel.callDuePMWorkOrderResponseObserver()
            ?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, pmResponseObserver)
    }

    private fun callPmDueFilterObserver() {
        if (mPMApiViewModel.callFilterPMWorkOrderResponseObserver()
                ?.hasActiveObservers()!!
        )
            mPMApiViewModel.callFilterPMWorkOrderResponseObserver()?.removeObserver(
                pmResponseObserver
            )!!

        pmResponseObserver = Observer { value ->
            if (mPMApiViewModel.mIsResponseForFilterDuePMWO) {
                if (value.apiStatus) {
                    showProgressDialog()

                } else {
                    mPMApiViewModel.mIsResponseForFilterDuePMWO = false
                    hideProgressDialog()
                    try {
                        if (value.response != null && !value.response.equals(getString(R.string.server_error))) {
                            if (value.response is PMDetailResponse) {
                                val mPmList =
                                    value.response as PMDetailResponse
                                if (mPmList.result?.size!! > 0) {
                                    //handleIncidentListApiResponse(mPmList, true)
                                    mDetailAdapter!!.clear()
                                    mDetailAdapter!!.removeHeader()
                                    mDetailAdapter!!.updateData(mPmList.result as ArrayList<PMDetailResponse.ResultBean>)
                                    mDetailAdapter!!.addHeader()
                                    mDetailAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                                } else
                                    showDialog(
                                        getString(R.string.error_msg),
                                        getString(R.string.no_response_server),
                                        true
                                    )
                            }
                        } else {
                            showToast(getString(R.string.server_error_loading_previous))
                            changeFragment(R.id.nav_drawer_pm_due_soon,Bundle(),false)

                        }

                    } catch (ex: SocketTimeoutException) {
                        ex.printStackTrace()
                        LogOperation.getLogger().logInfo(
                            LogLevel.INFO_LOG,
                            "callPmDueFilterObserver - Socket Time Out Exception : $ex"
                        )
                        showToast(getString(R.string.socket_timeout_error))
                    } catch (ex: Exception) {
                        ex.printStackTrace()
                        LogOperation.getLogger().logInfo(
                            LogLevel.INFO_LOG,
                            "callPmDueFilterObserver - Exception : $ex"
                        )
                        showToast(getString(R.string.exception_error))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        mPMApiViewModel.callFilterPMWorkOrderResponseObserver()
            ?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, pmResponseObserver)
    }




    private fun setObserverForDispatchToMeAPI() {

        mPMApiViewModel.dispatchToMe()
            ?.observe(this, Observer { value ->
                if (mPMApiViewModel.mIsFromDispatchApiCall) {
                    if (value.apiStatus) {
                        showProgressDialog()
                    } else {
                        mPMApiViewModel.mIsFromDispatchApiCall = false
                        hideProgressDialog()
                        try {
                            if (value.response is UpdateIncidentMessage) {
                                val responseValue = value.response as UpdateIncidentMessage
                                Log.d("CheckMyResponseValue", " - " + responseValue)
                                if (responseValue.result?.http_status?.equals("201")!!) {
                                    if (modelListUnchecked!!.size == 0) {
                                        mBindingFragmentGroupBinding.pmAssignedToDeviceRecycerparent.fragmentIncidentAssigntoDashboardRv!!.visibility =
                                            View.GONE
                                    }

                                    //showToast("Dispatched ")
                                    showDispatchDialog(
                                        resources.getString(R.string.dispatch_msg),
                                        responseValue.result?.status_message,true
                                    )


                                } else if (responseValue.result?.http_status?.equals("400")!! ||
                                    responseValue.result?.http_status?.equals("501")!!) {
                                    mDetailAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                                    showDispatchDialog(
                                        resources.getString(R.string.error_msg),
                                        responseValue.result?.status_message,false
                                    )

                                }
                                else {
                                    showDispatchDialog(
                                        resources.getString(R.string.error_msg),
                                        resources.getString(R.string.update_error_msg),
                                        false
                                    )

                                }
                            }
                        } catch (ex: SocketTimeoutException) {
                            ex.printStackTrace()
                            LogOperation.getLogger().logInfo(
                                LogLevel.INFO_LOG,
                                "setObserverForDispatchToMeAPI - Socket Time Out Exception : $ex"
                            )
                        } catch (ex: Exception) {
                            ex.printStackTrace()
                            LogOperation.getLogger().logInfo(
                                LogLevel.INFO_LOG,
                                "setObserverForDispatchToMeAPI - Exception : $ex"
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
    }


    fun showDialog(title: String?, message: String?, stayOnSameScreen: Boolean) {
        val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
        dialogBuilder.setMessage(message)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id ->
                dialog.dismiss()
                if (stayOnSameScreen) {
                    backToPreviousFragment(true)
                }
            })
        val alert = dialogBuilder.create()
        alert.setTitle(title)
        alert.show()
    }

    override fun onItemChangeListener(
        position: Int,
        model: PMDetailResponse.ResultBean
    ) {
        try {
            modelList!![position] = model
            mDetailAdapter!!.mAnythingChecked = true
        } catch (e: Exception) {
        }
    }

    private fun updateList(): ArrayList<PMDispatchRequest> {
        val temp = ArrayList<PMDetailResponse.ResultBean>()
        val jsonArray = ArrayList<PMDispatchRequest>()

        try {
            for (i in modelList!!.indices) {
                if (!modelList!![i].isChecked) {
                    temp.add(modelList!![i])
                }else{
                    Log.i("TAG", "Number[" + i + "]::" + modelList!![i].number)
                    jsonArray?.add(createDispatchPMToMeQuery(modelList!![i].number))
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
        }
        modelListUnchecked = temp

        /*  mDetailAdapter!!.setModel(modelListUnchecked as ArrayList<PMDetailResponse.ResultBean>)
          mDetailAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()*/

        return jsonArray
    }
    private fun createDispatchPMToMeQuery(number: String?): PMDispatchRequest {
        /*{
            "u_work_order_number": "WO0018180",
            "u_subcategory": "Preventative Maintenance",
            "u_category": "Device Maintenance",
            "u_assign_to": "Kchawla@plan-group.com"
        }*/
        val workOrder = PMDispatchRequest(number,"Preventative Maintenance","Device Maintenance",openedBy)

        return workOrder
    }
    fun createFilter(filterOptions: String, filterColumn: String) {
        if(filterOptions != ""){
            runQuery = if(filterOptions.startsWith("*")) {
                if(runQuery == "")
                    filterColumn+"LIKE"+filterOptions.substring(1)
                else
                    "$runQuery^"+filterColumn+"LIKE"+filterOptions.substring(1)
            }else {
                if (runQuery == "")
                    filterColumn+"STARTSWITH"+filterOptions
                else
                    "$runQuery^"+filterColumn+"STARTSWITH"+filterOptions
            }
        }
    }
    fun createPMFrequencyFilter(filterOptions: String, filterColumn: String) {
        var pmFilter = ""

        if(filterOptions != ""){
            pmFilter = pmFrequency(filterOptions)
            runQuery = if(pmFilter.startsWith("*")) {
                if(runQuery == "")
                    filterColumn+"IN"+ pmFilter.substring(1)
                else
                    "$runQuery^"+filterColumn+"IN"+pmFilter.substring(1)
            }else {
                if (runQuery == "")
                    filterColumn+"IN"+pmFilter
                else
                    "$runQuery^"+filterColumn+"IN"+pmFilter
            }
        }
    }
    private fun runPMFilter(): String {
        createFilter(mDetailAdapter!!.searchedNumber,"number")
        createFilter(mDetailAdapter!!.searchedCI,"cmdb_ci.name")
        createFilter(mDetailAdapter!!.searchedDeviceLocation,"location.name")
        createFilter(mDetailAdapter!!.searchedParent,"location.parent.name")
        createFilter(mDetailAdapter!!.searchedDispatchLocation,"u_dispatch_location.name")
        createFilter(mDetailAdapter!!.searchedRequestedDueBy,"requested_due_by")
        createPMFrequencyFilter(mDetailAdapter!!.searchedPMFrequency,"u_pm_frequency")
        createFilter(mDetailAdapter!!.searchedShortDesc,"short_description")

        Log.i("TAG", "runQuery::"+runQuery)
        if(runQuery.isNotEmpty()){
            //val runQueryLength = runQuery.length
            runQuery = runQuery.trim()
            runQuery += "/"
        }else{
            runQuery = ""
        }

        Log.i("finalQuery", "runQueryFinal::"+runQuery)

        return runQuery

    }
    fun pmFrequency(pmFrequency:String):String{
        var pmFreq = ""
        if(pmFrequency.startsWith("*")){
            pmFreq = pmFrequency.substring(1)
        }
        else{
            pmFreq = pmFrequency
        }
        if("Monthly".contains(pmFreq,ignoreCase = true)
            && "Yearly".contains(pmFreq,ignoreCase = true)){
            pmFreq = "Yearly,Monthly"
        }else if("Yearly".contains(pmFreq,ignoreCase = true)){
            pmFreq = "Yearly"
        }else if("Monthly".contains(pmFreq,ignoreCase = true)){
            //pmFreq = "*Monthly"
            pmFreq = "Monthly"
        }
        return pmFreq
    }
    fun showDispatchDialog(title: String?, message: String?,isSuccess:Boolean) {
        val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
        dialogBuilder.setMessage(message)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok), DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id ->
                if(!isSuccess) {
                    mDetailAdapter!!.setModel(modelList as ArrayList<PMDetailResponse.ResultBean>)
                    mDetailAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
                else{
                    mDetailAdapter!!.setModel(modelListUnchecked as ArrayList<PMDetailResponse.ResultBean>)
                    mDetailAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
                dialog.dismiss()

                changeFragment(R.id.nav_drawer_pm_due_soon,Bundle(),false)

                //backToPreviousFragment(false)
            })
        val alert = dialogBuilder.create()
        alert.setTitle(title)
        alert.show()
    }
    private fun pickFromDateTime() {
        val currentDateTime = Calendar.getInstance()
        val startYear = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val startMonth = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val startDay = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        val startHour = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
        val startMinute = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE)

        var mFromDatePicker = DatePickerDialog(requireContext(), DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { _, year, month, day ->
            TimePickerDialog(requireContext(), TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { _, hour, minute ->
                val pickedDateTime = Calendar.getInstance()
                pickedDateTime.set(year, month, day, hour, minute)
                val formatterDateTime = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH mm ss")
                val formatterDate = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
                var selectedFromDateTime = formatterDateTime.format(pickedDateTime.time)
                var selectedFromDate = formatterDate.format(pickedDateTime.time)
                Log.i(ContentValues.TAG, "selectedFromDateTime::$selectedFromDateTime")
                pickToDateTime(selectedFromDateTime)
            }, startHour, startMinute, false).show()
            /*val pickedDateTime = Calendar.getInstance()
            pickedDateTime.set(year, month, day)
            doSomethingWith(pickedDateTime)*/
        }, startYear, startMonth, startDay);
        mFromDatePicker.setTitle("FROM");
        mFromDatePicker.datePicker.maxDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
        mFromDatePicker.show()
    }
    private fun pickToDateTime(selectedDateTime1: String) {
        val currentDateTime = Calendar.getInstance()
        val startYear = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val startMonth = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val startDay = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        val startHour = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
        val startMinute = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE)

        var mToDatePicker = DatePickerDialog(requireContext(), DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { _, year, month, day ->
            TimePickerDialog(requireContext(), TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { _, hour, minute ->
                val pickedDateTime = Calendar.getInstance()
                pickedDateTime.set(year, month, day, hour, minute)
                val formatterDateTime = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH mm ss")
                var selectedFromDateTime = formatterDateTime.format(pickedDateTime.time)
                Log.i(ContentValues.TAG, "selectedToDateTime::$selectedFromDateTime")

            }, startHour, startMinute, false).show()
            /* val pickedToDateTime = Calendar.getInstance()
             pickedToDateTime.set(year, month, day)
             doCallChangeFragment(selectedDateTime, pickedToDateTime)*/
        }, startYear, startMonth, startDay);
        mToDatePicker.setTitle("TO");
        mToDatePicker.datePicker.maxDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
        mToDatePicker.show()
    }
}
```

This code is being used to pick up from date,time and to date, time using calender feature for filtering data for particular period but the data is not getting filtered, the data for all the month is being displayed .So I need to add local filter for filtering data according to specific date and time using calendar feature.